# How to enter url in browser to open PDF file to bookmark

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I entered a bookmark for a chapter title "Introduction" on page 2 and when I try to open the PDF file in a browser to this bookmark, it appears correctly in Chrome on page 2, but Safari and Firefox always open the file on page 1.

I'm using Acrobat X Pro. The url I'm using is:

https://www.mydomain.com/path/to/myPdfFile.pdf#nameddest=Introduction

Is bookmark the same as named destination?

Anyone familiar with Acrobat X Pro can shed some light on this?

How does one create a named destination if not by creating a bookmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. A bookmark is NOT a named destination.

To view the named destinations:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7cab.w.html

Basically, you need to do this:

`Choose View > Show/Hide > Navigation Panes > Destinations. All destinations are automatically scanned.`

To add a named destination:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7ca7.w.html

Basically, do this:

`Navigate to the location where you want to create a destination, and set the desired view. In the Destinations panel, choose New Destination from the options menu , and name the destination. Save the target document.`